# html pagedisplay in activity

Tags: java, android

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
WebView detailsLink=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view);
detailsLink.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
detailsLink.loadUrl(bundle.getString("keyLink"));
```

This is code for displaying whole web page within Activity. But I want to display particular part of web page within Activity. I have try for this but not display particular Part this is code for that please tell me where I m doing wrong.

```
detailsLink.loadUrl(url, extraHeaders)
String detailsLink1="<html><body><iframe src='keyLink' width='100%' height='100' 
scrolling='no'> </iframe></body></html>";           
detailsLink.loadData(detailsLink1, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

From reading your code, I think you need to change this line:

```
String detailsLink1="<html><body><iframe src='keyLink' width='100%' height='100' 
scrolling='no'> </iframe></body></html>";
```

to

```
String link = bundle.getString("keyLink");
String detailsLink1="<html><body><iframe src='" + link + "' width='100%' height='100'  scrolling='no'> </iframe></body></html>";
```

Notice, I'm setting the 'src' for the iframe to the url in the intent.  You also don't need to call `loadUrl()` since you're manually specifying the HTML to display.

Answer (score 0):

First read your `keyLink` string from bundle.

```
String link = bundle.getString("keyLink");
```

and append it to your `HTML` `String` `detailsLink1` as

```
String detailsLink1="<html><body><iframe src='" + link + "' width='100%' height='100'  scrolling='no'> </iframe></body></html>";
```

Since you are loading String variable of html (not a url, url is appended in `detailsLink1` ), you should do following to load the String variable `detailsLink1` into `detailsLink`

```
detailsLink.loadData(detailsLink1, "text/html", "utf-8");
```